# Invalid use of property while delete cells

Tags: excel, vba

What am I doing wrong ?

```
MAJPRIXFORMAT.Cells(x, "C").Delete shift: xlToLeft
```

return me : "Invalid use of property" and highlight `xlToLeft`

`MAJPRIXFORMAT` is a var worksheet

This line should delete a cells and moove other cells to the left..

Comment: `MAJPRIXFORMAT.Cells(x, "C").Delete` will shift to left by default (for me at least). Btw, hope you don't mind but I voted to close since this appears to be a typo.

Comment: @JvdV Mistake happens ;) ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `=` sign:

```
MAJPRIXFORMAT.Cells(x, "C").Delete shift:=xlToLeft
```

Comment: what a silly issue, thank you. Will accept answer in 10 min